# Play video from assets in native player

Tags: android

I need to play a **3gp** file which is stored in the assets folder.

Also i require to play the video in **native android player** not in the video view please help me i struck at this
thanks in advance
jibysthomas

Answer (score 1):

If you were to put your file in the *res/raw* folder rather than the assets folder (any reason why you can't do this?), you could use the `MediaPlayer` class.  This sample assumes you have your file in *res/ra*w and the file is thus assigned a resource ID and can be accessed via `R.raw.my3gpFile` for the `resId` parameter.

```
private void playResource(Context context, int resId) {
            MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(context, resId);
            player.start();

            player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.release();
                }
            });         
        }
```

Comment: i have much more file as videos so it requires assets folder to put these files....thanks for quick reply